# Tkinter: how to bind scale hotkeys?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to bind Control+MouseWheelUp combination.
I tried to do so:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Control-Button-4>',print)
```

This gives no reaction? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<MouseWheel>` to bind the mouse wheel:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Control-MouseWheel>', lambda e: print('f'))

root.mainloop()
```